# chrome.gcm is only available to apps and extensions, how do I use it as a normal website?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, service-worker, web-push, push-api

I have heard that push notifications are now supported in Chrome (including Android) as a website, but the documents I can find talk about chrome.gcm as only available in a Chrome App or Chrome Extension. What do I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[chrome.gcm](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/gcm) was a proprietary push API built for Chrome Apps and Extensions which the user has to install.

There is a new API called Push API ([spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/push-api/)) which is a web standard based on [service workers](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/service-worker/introduction/), and available to normal websites.

This walkthrough explains how to send notifications from your website and should get you up and running: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/